# Arrays wrapped in complex type are unwrapped in Java code (Axis 1.4)

Tags: java, web-services, serialization, axis

The WSDL looks like this:

```xml
<xsd:element name="Parent">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="tns:Child"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

## Expected behavior

If I let Axis 1.4 generate Java code based on the WSDL, I expect the following field in my object:

```java
public class MyComplexObject {
    private Parent parent;
}
```

The `Parent` class would consist of an array of `Child` objects.

```java
public class Parent {
    private Child[] child;
}
```

## Actual behavior

The actual behavior is that the list of `Child` objects is defined directly on the parent object level:

```java
public class MyComplexObject {
    private Child[] parent;
}
```

When we call the webservice by filling the array, It will result in the following XML:

```xml
<Parent>
    ...
</Parent>
<Parent>
    ...
</Parent>
```

causing failures on the server side. It seems that Axis has difficulties with nested arrays of complex types. Anyone facing the same issue and knowing any workaround/fix?

## Findings

After some investigation I was able to produce expected behavior by adding a dummy field to the XSD definition:

```xml
<xsd:element name="Parent">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Dummy" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="tns:Child"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

It seems that, in this case, Axis correctly creates a `Parent` wrapper object:

```java
public class Parent {
    private String dummy;
    private Child[] child;
}
```

And my XML output is correct:

```xml
<Parent>
    <Dummy>...</Dummy>
    <Child>...</Child>
    <Child>...</Child>
</Parent>
```

So it seems that this is really a bug in Axis 1.4...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently found a solution for this. `wsdl2java` seems to have an undocumented `-w` option which is shorthand for `--wrapArrays`. If you generate your classes using SoapUI, you're able to select this option:

[image: SoapUI and wsdl2java]

As stated, this option will create classes for "certain schema array patterns", such as the pattern outlined in my question.

If you're using Eclipse to generate a web service client, you can configure the same kind of option by going to Axis Emitter under Eclipse's Preferences and checking the according checkbox.

[image: Eclipse and wsdl2java]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `-W` option at the `wsdl2java` command?

From the [Tools reference](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html):

> **-W, --noWrapped**
>       This turns off the special treatment of what is called "wrapped" document/literal style operations. By default, WSDL2Java will
>   recognize the following conditions:
>
> - If an input message has is a single part.
> - The part is an element.
> - The element has the same name as the operation
> - **The element's complex type has no attributes**
>
>   When it sees this, WSDL2Java will 'unwrap' the top level element, and treat each of the components of the element as arguments to the
>     operation. This type of WSDL is the default for Microsoft .NET web
>     services, which wrap up RPC style arguments in this top level schema
>     element.

Maybe this could fix it.

Comment: This didn't did the trick, but nice try :) Good point though to look further into those tool parameters.